# Append data from different model in json object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to implement Like function in my rails app.
What I do for now is I have model Question, Answer and Like.

Basically, 
**Question model** has question details for example user_id, question_text, **Answer model** has answer details for example user_id, answer_text and **Like model** has relationship for like between user_id, question_id, and answer_id.

In my Question controller, I want to render Question details page, where it will shows us a question and few answers. 
I have render the question json, and answers related to the question.

```
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Turtoise",
      "user_id": 22
    }
  ],
  "answers": [
    {
      "id": 41,
      "question_id": 1,
      "user_id": 17,
      "text": "Good"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "question_id": 1,
      "user_id": 17,
      "text": "alifff"
    }
  ],
  "isLike": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "user_id": "17",
      "question_id": "1",
      "answer_id": null,
      "isLike": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to render the json like this

```
   {
  "questions": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Turtoise",
      "isLike": {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": "17",
        "question_id": "1",
        "answer_id": null,
        "isLike": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "answers": [
    {
      "id": 7,
      "text": "Good",
      "isLike": {
        "id": 2,
        "user_id": "17",
        "question_id": null,
        "answer_id": "8",
        "isLike": false
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "text": "Nice",
      "isLike": {
        "id": 3,
        "user_id": "17",
        "question_id": null,
        "answer_id": "8",
        "isLike": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can you give me some idea how to do this.

Comment: you json not format properly. please correct it.

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin I have correcting my json

Comment: you will probably need to over ride the as_json method in the model. Include whatever you want to include in the options hash. and then you are good to go. For some reasons I feel you need to relook at your json that you want to render. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: I'm using Postgresql .. @KaranPurohit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to play with rails relationship here.

General speaking, your `Question hasMany Like, and Like belongsTo Question`. Same goes to Answer, `Answer hasMany Like, and Like belongsTo Answer`.

Since `Like` can `belongsTo` more than one model, you can try using `Polymorphism Association`.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to do it and let you know the progress.